# Do not run some Checkstyle rules in a specific Maven profile

Tags: maven, checkstyle

We use a different profile for development, and a different profile for the CI. The latter is more strict in the manner of Checkstyle rules. My question is: how can i easily *turn off executing some of the rules in the development profile*? One possible solution is just using `configLocation` property in the `maven-checkstyle-plugin`, and adding the different configs in two locations:

```
<profile>
    <id>CI</id>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>ci-checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>development</id>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>dev-checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

However this leads to the duplication of the check file. Is there a way to dynamically skip parts of the file?

**Edit**: my motivation is that we run the Checkstyle rules when developing in Eclipse, in the incremental compilation (every time when a file is saved) and also when compiling from Maven command line. This is very convenient, but there are some rules which take a [long time](http://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/1064), and that makes this kind of development impossible, so i want to turn them off.

Comment: What about creating a third config file, e.g. `checks-for-all-envs.xml`, consolidating all three with each other and adding a build step for the third to each of the profiles?

Comment: You mean in the CI profile, i shold ran CS twice (two maven executions), once with dev checkcs and then (all - dev)? And in the dev profile, just ran dev checks?

Comment: No. In profile `CI` declare build steps for `ci-checks` and `checks-for-all-envs.` In profile `development` declare build steps for `dev-checks` and `checks-for-all-envs.` `checks-for-all-envs.xml` is supposed to contain checks that are perfomed on both. The others are supposed to contain checks for their specific environment only.

Comment: I see. So the point is to run multiple CS executions in one profile. Thanks for the suggestion!